# How to change Class of a div using on click of using ngClass

Tags: angular, angular6, ng-class

I have a button tag, upon clicking on what, it should change the class of a div tag.I'm using `ngFor`, so each row should be treated individually.

Here's the snippet of my code and what I want to do.

```
  <div *ngFor="let item of users">
  <button class="fas fa-angle-up"></button>
  <strong>NAME </strong>{{item.attribute.name}}
  <div class="pf-m-expanded">Some Content Here</div> <!--This is the class that has to toggle upon clicking that **button**>
  </div>
```

What I want to do is upon clicking the button, I should be able to toggle(remove and activate class) `pf-m-expanded`.
And since it is a `*ngFor`, It should **treat each row individually**.

Comment: which class you want to toggle on click of button?

Comment: @SnehaPawar `pf-m-expanded`

Comment: yeah, but you want to replace this class with another class right?

Comment: @SnehaPawar nooo, actually removing that class will hide the div and activating the class will again show the div.Hide/Show (toggle).That is what I want to achieve

Comment: @SnehaPawar so If i'll remove the `pf-m-expanded`,it'll hide the div,but I want to do that on a button click.That is my problem.And it is under ngFor so I want that It'll only hide that row whose **button was clicked**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can define a local variable inside the loop, and have the button to toggle the value of the variable, then have [ngClass] to add/remove the class based on the value of the variable.

```
<div *ngFor="let item of users; let toggle = true;">
  <button class="fas fa-angle-up" (click)="toggle = !toggle">Test</button>
  <strong>NAME </strong>{{item.attribute.name}}
  <div [ngClass]="{ 'pf-m-expanded': toggle }">
    Some Content Here
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Will it treat all the rows individually?.

Comment: And any idea how to change the logo of the `fa-angle-up` to `fa-angle-down` upon clicking?.

Comment: yep it's a local variable for each row

Comment: `{ 'fa-angle-up': toggle, 'fa-angle-down': !toggle }`